# In VS Code, how can I disable suggestions in code comments?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every time I type out periods in a comment, VS Code attempts to autocomplete with some code suggestion.

[image: undesirable autocomplete]

As a result, I always have to type out some extra keys (eg `esc`) before pressing `enter` to complete my line, so that vscode doesn't mistakingly add some irrelevant and undesired auto-completion.

How do I disable all suggestions, snippets, autocomplete, intellisense, etc.. for comments in vscode?

I've tried many different settings for `suggest` and `snippet`, I still cannot disable them.

The oft-quoted setting is `editor.quickSuggestions.comments`, but this has not worked for me:

```json
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
  "other": "on",
  "comments": "off",
  "strings": "off"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this option is language specific and can't be applied globally. What you should do is to open your "settings.json" file, find/create python specific config and then paste "editor.quickSuggestions" parameter inside, like so:

```
"[python]": {
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "comments": false
  }
},
```

Worked for me with Lua.

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work for me.